# Show/Hide ColumnGroups with a mix of hidden and displayed columns

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I've got a RadGrid with programmatically generated columns, including a variable number of column groups. Each of the column groups contains four columns, two that are displayed and two that are not.

Above the RadGrid I have a series of checkboxes, one for each column group. The goal is to have the user check or uncheck the boxes depending on what columns they wish to see. Currently I am setting the columns' Display properties when a checkbox's checked value is changed by using `radgrid.Columns.FindByUniqueName("columnName").Display`. However the column group itself cannot be accessed this way. As it is, the column groups disappear when all their child columns disappear, but they do not reappear when their child columns are displayed, causing the headers to become misaligned.

Relevant code:

```
'Defining the grid
Dim radgrid As RadGrid
radgrid = New RadGrid()

Dim i as Integer = 0
For Each r As DataRow In subTable.Rows
    Dim colGroup As GridColumnGroup = New GridGroupColumn()
    radgrid.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.Add(colGroup)
    colGroup.HeaderText = r.Item("Name")
    colGroup.Name = "colGroup" & i

    Dim colID As GridBoundColumn = New GridBoundColumn()
    radgrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(colID)
    colID.ColumnGroupName = "colGroup" & i
    colID.DataField = "id" & i
    colID.HeaderText = "ID"
    colID.UniqueName = "id" & i
    colID.Display = False

    Dim colScore As GridBoundColumn = New GridBoundColumn()
    radgrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(colScore)
    colScore.ColumnGroupName = "colGroup" & i
    colScore.DataField = "score" & i
    colScore.HeaderText = "Score"
    colScore.UniqueName = "score" & i

    i += 1
Next

'Checkbox CheckedChanged sub
If selectedButton.Checked = True Then
    radgrid.Columns.FindByUniqueName("colScore" & selectedButton.Value.ToString()).Display = True
Else
    radgrid.Columns.FindByUniqueName("colScore" & selectedButton.Value.ToString()).Display = False
End If
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like `radgrid.MasterTableView.ColumnGroups.FindGroupByName("colGroup" & selectedButton.Value.ToString()).Display = False` but there is no `Display` property for that and the `Visible` property is ReadOnly. I've also tried re-setting the `ColumnGroupName` of the columns after setting them to display, but that also does not work.

I'm guessing the fact that I have hidden columns is what's making this more complicated than it should be, but is there a way to get this to work with hidden columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution actually turned up when I was working on a somewhat unrelated issue.

Calling `radgrid.Rebind()` after changing the value of the `Display` property causes the group column headers to disappear and reappear as desired.

```
Protected Sub button_CheckChanged()
    If selectedButton.Checked = True Then
        radgrid.Columns.FindByUniqueName("colScore" & selectedButton.Value.ToString()).Display = True
    Else
        radgrid.Columns.FindByUniqueName("colScore" & selectedButton.Value.ToString()).Display = False
    End If
    radgrid.Rebind()
End Sub
```